# bash script to redirect the output of 'cut' / 'find' to 'scp' with some transformations applied

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, pipe

I need to redirect the output of `cut` / `find` to `scp` with filename transformations applied in between.

**Background:**

I am using clearcase for version control. I have branch `feature` brached off of `/Main`. I want to `scp` all the files from `feature` branch and their original version at `/Main` to other machine.

I know the command to list the files I have changed on `feature` branch, I can get the original copy too.

**This is what I tried:**

I have created an alias `filefinder` to list files from a branch.

Which uses `find` to find all the files from `feature` branch.

```
$ filefinder `feature` | cut -d '/' -f 2 -

a.c

b.c

c.h

d.h
```

So, if I try e.g.

```
$ scp $(filefinder KERN_414_A64 | cut -d '/' -f 2) test@ip:/path/
```

I can `scp` all the files on the `feature` branch.

**Requirement:**

In order to get the `/main/latest` version of the file. I have to modify the name of the files as

```
a.c@@/Main

b.c@@/Main

c.h@@/Main
```

and then `scp` *those* files. So basically, edit the output of `find` / `cut` command before feeding it to `scp`

I could change my branch to `/Main/latest` if nothing works, but trying to find the better way.

Any pointers will be helpful.

**Update**

`filefinder` alias:

`cleartool find . -type f -branch "brtype($1)" -print | awk -F"@" '{print $1}'`

Thanks!

Comment: Please include your alias `filefinder` definiton in the question

Comment: Is this using GNU tools (or, if it's easier to answer, is it a Linux-based platform)

Comment: Yep it is linux based platform... Updated the answer with `filefinder` alias

Comment: `c.h@@/Main` - you cannot have a slash in the filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of a concrete definition for `filefinder` I'm going to assume it's something like this (but see below for an update)

```
filefinder() { find "$1" -type f; }
```

I'm slightly concerned that if you're copying a number of files named like this

```
a.c@@/Main
b.c@@/Main
c.h@@/Main
```

you're going to end up with one file on the target called `Main`. I've assumed, therefore, that for `a.c@@/Main` the target is supposed to remain as `a.c`

Now, instead of using `filefinder` you can just copy the files in one operation. I've built this solution so that it can be parameterised just like the `filefinder` (above):

```
filecopier() {
    find "$1" -type f -exec bash -c '
        for file in "$@"
        do
            file="${file#*/}"
            echo scp -p "${file}@@/Main" test@ip:"/path/${file##*/}"
        done
    ' _ {} +
}
```

Remove the `echo` from `scp` when you are happy the commands are correct.

---

So it seems that `filefinder` isn't as straightforward as I'd guessed. Nevertheless we can still use a similar approach

```
filefinder ... |
    while IFS= read -r file
    do
        echo scp -p "${file}@@/Main" test@ip:"/path/${file##*/}"
    done
```

This presupposes your file names are one-per-line, without awkward characters such as newline.

Comment: Thank you for the quick solution. However, what is the use of `IFS` here ? What is the side effect if I used `while read -r file` . 
Because I tried that and it gave me exact same output. So I am wondering where will it fail? also my file names are not weird and one per line :)

Comment: `IFS= read -r` is a combination that stops `read` parsing its input and potentially reducing multiple whitespace. As an example, try `echo ' x y  \z ' | ( IFS= read -r item; echo "$item" )`with and without the `IFS=` component. You'll see the leading and trailing whitespace get stripped without `IFS=` and the backslash stripped without the `-r`.